# QtNetwork SSL Handshake error on https://service.oneaccount.com/onlineV2_B/OSV2?event=login&pt=3

Tags: qt, ssl, qtnetwork

When I use my QT application to download this page: https://service.oneaccount.com/onlineV2_B/OSV2?event=login&pt=3 with QNetworkAccessManager->get(url), I got a network error (QNetworkReply::NetworkError) in the reply object. The error string is SSL handshake failed. However, the sslErrors signal is not fired so I don't even get the chance to ignore this error. I got the same problem on Mac and Windows version.

If I do the same thing with QT 4.74. It works fine.

Answer (score 2):

Using `QSslSocket::setProtocol(QSsl:SslV3)` fixes the problem.

Comment: Can you please provide more details please?