# QT ssl error on hotmail.com: The issuer certificate of a locally looked up certificate could not be found

Tags: qt, ssl, openssl, qtwebkit

When I use QtWebkit (which uses QSslSocket internally) to connect to www.hotmail.com, I got the following ssl errors after logging in:

1. The issuer certificate of a locally looked up certificate could not be found
2. The root CA certificate is not trusted for this purpose
3. No certifiates could be verified.

I could get the same errors at mail.yahoo.com before logging in. 
I have found that secure connection to these two servers triggers the ssl errors:

1. https://gfx8.hotmail.com
2. https://csc.beap.bc.yahoo.com

There is a small ssl demo program included with QT called securesocketclient. I can produce the same errors if I use this little client to connect to port 443 of the above two servers. I am 99% certain this is a bug with QT since we have produced this issue on many development systems. It affects linux, mac and windows QT. It affects QT 4.7.4 all the way to QT 4.8.4 (didn't try earlier versions). The bug is reproduced with openssl 0.9.8.

Some people might falsely claim that the bug is fixed by using openssl 1.0.0 with precompiled QT binary. That's wrong since the precompiled QT binary is compiled with openssl 0.9.8 header files. Openssl 0.9.8 is not binary compatible with openssl 1.0.0. Some of the structure memebers will be misinterpreted if you compile QT with one version of openssl but use another version of openssl binary. I did a lot of step-and-trace into QT and openssl source code to arrive at this conclusion.

Since hotmail and yahoo email are extremely popular websites, I'd consider this bug is a serious bug in terms of security for QT. I already reported it to QT bug system (https://bugreports.qt.io/browse/QTBUG-23625) and I doubt when digia will ever get their hands on it based on my past experience.

Please feel free to share your thoughts on how to fix this bug. I do know how to call ignoreSslErrors and pretend there is no problem. But that's not how openssl is intended to be used.

---

**Some updates from further investigation on this issue.**

The certificate path for https://gfx8.hotmail.com is:

- Root CA: Versign Class 3 Public Primary Certification Authority - G5
- Intermediate CA: Versign Class 3 Extended Validation SSL SGC CA
- Server Certificate: gfx-ecn.hotmail.com

The root CA does sit in the Windows certificate store and is loaded properly at startup. I guess perhaps somehow QT doesn't get the intermediate certificate. I run a test with the openssl command line program as shown below:

> openssl s_client -showcerts -connect gfx8.hotmail.com:443

The output is here:

> CONNECTED(000001AC) depth=0 1.3.6.1.4.1.311.60.2.1.3 = US,
>   1.3.6.1.4.1.311.60.2.1.2 = Washington, bu sinessCategory = Private Organization, serialNumber = 600413485, C = US, postalC ode = 98052,
>   ST = Washington, L = Redmond, street = 1 Microsoft Way, O = Microso ft
>   Corporation, OU = Windows Azure CDN, CN = gfx-ecn.hotmail.com
>
> verify error:num=20:unable to get local issuer certificate verify
>   return:1
>
> depth=0 1.3.6.1.4.1.311.60.2.1.3 = US, 1.3.6.1.4.1.311.60.2.1.2 =
>   Washington, bu sinessCategory = Private Organization, serialNumber =
>   600413485, C = US, postalC ode = 98052, ST = Washington, L = Redmond,
>   street = 1 Microsoft Way, O = Microso ft Corporation, OU = Windows
>   Azure CDN, CN = gfx-ecn.hotmail.com
>
> verify error:num=27:certificate not trusted verify return:1
>
> depth=0 1.3.6.1.4.1.311.60.2.1.3 = US, 1.3.6.1.4.1.311.60.2.1.2 =
>   Washington, bu sinessCategory = Private Organization, serialNumber =
>   600413485, C = US, postalC ode = 98052, ST = Washington, L = Redmond,
>   street = 1 Microsoft Way, O = Microso ft Corporation, OU = Windows
>   Azure CDN, CN = gfx-ecn.hotmail.com
>
> verify error:num=21:unable to verify the first certificate verify
>   return:1
>
> Certificate chain  0
>   s:/1.3.6.1.4.1.311.60.2.1.3=US/1.3.6.1.4.1.311.60.2.1.2=Washington/businessCategory=Private
>   Organization/serialNumber=600413485/C=US/postalCode=98052/ST=Washington/L=Redmond/street=1
>   Microsoft Way/O=Microsoft Corporation/OU=Windows Azure
>   CDN/CN=gfx-ecn.hotmail.com    i:/C=US/O=VeriSign, Inc./OU=VeriSign
>   Trust Network/OU=Terms of use at https://www.verisign.com/rpa
>   (c)06/CN=VeriSign Class 3 Extended Validation SSL SGC CA
>
> -----BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----
>
> MIIG0DCCBbigAwIBAgIQfRbsuTLd2GrmU38TPnVOCTANBgkqhkiG9w0BAQUFADCB
>   vjELMAkGA1UEBhMCVVMxFzAVBgNVBAoTDlZlcmlTaWduLCBJbmMuMR8wHQYDVQQL
>   ExZWZXJpU2lnbiBUcnVzdCBOZXR3b3JrMTswOQYDVQQLEzJUZXJtcyBvZiB1c2Ug
>   YXQgaHR0cHM6Ly93d3cudmVyaXNpZ24uY29tL3JwYSAoYykwNjE4MDYGA1UEAxMv
>   VmVyaVNpZ24gQ2xhc3MgMyBFeHRlbmRlZCBWYWxpZGF0aW9uIFNTTCBTR0MgQ0Ew
>   HhcNMTIxMTA3MDAwMDAwWhcNMTQxMTA4MjM1OTU5WjCCAR0xEzARBgsrBgEEAYI3
>   PAIBAxMCVVMxGzAZBgsrBgEEAYI3PAIBAhMKV2FzaGluZ3RvbjEdMBsGA1UEDxMU
>   UHJpdmF0ZSBPcmdhbml6YXRpb24xEjAQBgNVBAUTCTYwMDQxMzQ4NTELMAkGA1UE
>   BhMCVVMxDjAMBgNVBBEUBTk4MDUyMRMwEQYDVQQIEwpXYXNoaW5ndG9uMRAwDgYD
>   VQQHFAdSZWRtb25kMRgwFgYDVQQJFA8xIE1pY3Jvc29mdCBXYXkxHjAcBgNVBAoU
>   FU1pY3Jvc29mdCBDb3Jwb3JhdGlvbjEaMBgGA1UECxQRV2luZG93cyBBenVyZSBD
>   RE4xHDAaBgNVBAMUE2dmeC1lY24uaG90bWFpbC5jb20wggEiMA0GCSqGSIb3DQEB
>   AQUAA4IBDwAwggEKAoIBAQC+jRmBRv2iw1N2LirFdhgqmZ3G+BBc8gAn50O6TT1u
>   zNqrjicf3KJ+BDHSGcnkysvWovwnUhDhMzAWf521iYi2lFZqC3txewGvjrKM0Gqz
>   DhHrF+bzvNjyrIION89354cFxU1eK2okegYHkWIuyPHyCN6PFGK52OlkBixb34xv
>   WvAZfjSu/hr+f+lkedFZvJdd6KS4e8N/tGJ/dndfmReaKSiNFWBFbwhkndLdXU3p
>   ZnVLCysETMuUoIsDIPcgDfji1XkoKLsri9WijVhjNH1MFf/t6/g4PpWqZGl4si3t
>   yQ0rdefDGfgX8lvq63aXnaap4SbjTYLviFRle/PMkXV7AgMBAAGjggJmMIICYjCB
>   0AYDVR0RBIHIMIHFghBnZngxLmhvdG1haWwuY29tghBnZngyLmhvdG1haWwuY29t
>   ghBnZngzLmhvdG1haWwuY29tghBnZng0LmhvdG1haWwuY29tghBnZng1LmhvdG1h
>   aWwuY29tghBnZng2LmhvdG1haWwuY29tghBnZng3LmhvdG1haWwuY29tghBnZng4
>   LmhvdG1haWwuY29tghRncmFwaGljcy5ob3RtYWlsLmNvbYIIYS5nZngubXOCE2dm
>   eC1lY24uaG90bWFpbC5jb20wCQYDVR0TBAIwADAdBgNVHQ4EFgQUH0b2ApITW9WB
>   /LA+oaz+2ZnW/dwwDgYDVR0PAQH/BAQDAgWgMD4GA1UdHwQ3MDUwM6AxoC+GLWh0
>   dHA6Ly9FVkludGwtY3JsLnZlcmlzaWduLmNvbS9FVkludGwyMDA2LmNybDBEBgNV
>   HSAEPTA7MDkGC2CGSAGG+EUBBxcGMCowKAYIKwYBBQUHAgEWHGh0dHBzOi8vd3d3
>   LnZlcmlzaWduLmNvbS9jcHMwNAYDVR0lBC0wKwYIKwYBBQUHAwEGCCsGAQUFBwMC
>   BglghkgBhvhCBAEGCisGAQQBgjcKAwMwHwYDVR0jBBgwFoAUTkPIHXbvN1N6T/JY
>   b5TzOOLVvd8wdgYIKwYBBQUHAQEEajBoMCsGCCsGAQUFBzABhh9odHRwOi8vRVZJ
>   bnRsLW9jc3AudmVyaXNpZ24uY29tMDkGCCsGAQUFBzAChi1odHRwOi8vRVZJbnRs
>   LWFpYS52ZXJpc2lnbi5jb20vRVZJbnRsMjAwNi5jZXIwDQYJKoZIhvcNAQEFBQAD
>   ggEBAFdVsrzkxJ6aRnaGIO1hbCDlekEMCT6OTlZXckzZeaIrNfSFLXHe89pWkRr1
>   AKz43nnM0pLxVuEHRE9pMZH6Om7SjqU5BR1qd6xp+ZJhuJA2I2319PCSbKCpv67X
>   82J8/JKjH8e4fpOzb70dKUlNNr7x0aIMYuCq6unXXZQ5u83Uny42jcIQWLOlZRKC
>   dYSqW3JalTYVZNvdEoQVuUEJJLcY1qMVJ9NFtdnrzrmcpK+52+nZQXbCkM7W8Vl1
>   WM/dbOnqsu0+SIPZ4Q2wIAnT1azmBvxZ2ULvzW98HIAn4/RdPuimnox8T9R2yrv1
>   xd5P6oAZWvmnX6e461m6HohhhDw=
>
> -----END CERTIFICATE-----
>
> Server certificate
>   subject=/1.3.6.1.4.1.311.60.2.1.3=US/1.3.6.1.4.1.311.60.2.1.2=Washington/businessCategory=Private
>   Organization/serialNumber=600413485/C=US/postalCode=98052/ST=Washington/L=Redmond/street=1
>   Microsoft Way/O=Microsoft Corporation/OU=Windows Azure
>   CDN/CN=gfx-ecn.hotmail.com issuer=/C=US/O=VeriSign, Inc./OU=VeriSign
>   Trust Network/OU=Terms of use at https://www.verisign.com/rpa
>   (c)06/CN=VeriSign Class 3 Extended Validation SSL SGC CA
>
> No client certificate CA names sent
>
> SSL handshake has read 1933 bytes and written 480 bytes
>
> New, TLSv1/SSLv3, Cipher is AES256-SHA Server public key is 2048 bit
>   Secure Renegotiation IS supported Compression: NONE Expansion: NONE
>   SSL-Session:
>       Protocol  : SSLv3
>       Cipher    : AES256-SHA
>       Session-ID: 3CC559C15AF17B09346C371A1CB292DF77C272A37FDC4DF69EEE0EE9CC067B5C
>       Session-ID-ctx: 
>       Master-Key: F626E23FDCC89B1329FD4F5D1ED5A940F0CB14A1C377BFDB6ABA6238B91F9C11390EC16FD117C090B3171FBEE762B792
>       Key-Arg   : None
>       PSK identity: None
>       PSK identity hint: None
>       Start Time: 1355423684
>       Timeout   : 7200 (sec)
>       Verify return code: 21 (unable to verify the first certificate)

From the output of openssl, we can see that the openssl program produces similar errors (which makes it look more like an openssl bug?). We also notice that the hotmail server only returns the server certificate but does not return the intermediate certificate. That's probably what caused the error. I tried the same ssl command with other https servers. They also return both server certificates and intermediate certificates. Some of the banking sites I've tested even returned the entire certificate chain all the way to the root CA. So, the question is, if the intermediate certificate is not returned, how and where am I supposed to get it from? How does other browsers like IE and chrome handle this?

---

**More findings here.**

Actually, both of the two servers I mentioned are used to download in-page components for hotmail and yahoo mail. The yahoo mail main login page itself does return the full certificate chain. When other browsers access the main page, it will store the intermediate certificates locally for later use. However, QTWebkit doesn't cache the intermediate certificates automatically, therefore causing the problem. If I access the server https://gfx8.hotmail.com directly with a fresh copy of firefox, I get the same error. But if I access https:/www.hotmail.com first and then log into hotmail, there is no error although some components are downloaded from the gfx8 server after login. I found QTWebkit neither loads the intermediate certificates from system certificate store, nor does it add intermediate certificates to the system certificate store. It doesn't cache intermediate certificates internally in memory either. That will cause problem for some servers which doesn't return the complete certificate chain.

I did try saving the intermediate certificates to PEM file and load it at startup of my application. It works fine on Windows and Linux. But somehow, it has no effect on Mac. Don't know why.

Comment: Did you ever figure out how to get Qt to use intermediate certificates?

Answer (score 4):

In order to support secure connections in your application, without ignorig ssl errors, you must have the root certificates of all the domains that the site you're loading is accessing, so for example if it accesses a CDN(chech in the net panel of your browser), get that server's certificates also (you can download them from chrome for example, by viewing the current site's certificates, and get the whole chain, but separately download them).
After you stored all these certificates in one separate folder, add this code somewhere after the initialization of your application, it will load all of them at the beginning, so QT can access them:

```
import os

from PySide.QtNetwork import QSsl, QSslConfiguration, QSslCertificate
from PySide.QtCore import QFile, QIODevice


def load_certs(cert_path):
    # cert_path is a string "/path/to/cert/files"
    ssl_config = QSslConfiguration.defaultConfiguration()
    ssl_config.setProtocol(QSsl.SecureProtocols)

    certs = ssl_config.caCertificates()

    for cert_filename in os.listdir(cert_path):
        if os.path.splitext(cert_filename)[1] in ('.cer', '.crt', '.pem'):
            cert_filepath = os.path.join(cert_path, cert_filename)
            cert_file = QFile(cert_filepath)
            cert_file.open(QIODevice.ReadOnly)
            cert = QSslCertificate(cert_file)
            certs.append(cert)

    ssl_config.setCaCertificates(certs)
    QSslConfiguration.setDefaultConfiguration(ssl_config)
```

Now when a site requires certificate validation, it won't fail. However openssl has indeed problems with it's TLS implementation on Debian systems, and in those cases you will experience problems such as pages never load, or similar errors when you don't have valid certificates. In those cases you have to force using SSLv3 for those pages, to get them work. You can achieve that by binding a custom virtual function to *QNetworkAccessManager*'s *createRequest*, and overriding the ssl protocol for each request. That way you don't have to rely on older ssl version for all sites(because you could set the default ssl protocol globally too, but that's not the best idea), only for those which are problematic:

```
class Browser(object):

    def __init__(self):
        self.network_manager = QNetworkAccessManager()
        self.network_manager.createRequest = self._create_request
        self.web_page = QWebPage()
        self.web_page.setNetworkAccessManager(self.network_manager)
        self.web_view = QWebView()
        self.web_view.setPage(self.web_page)
        self._override_ssl = None

    def _create_request(self, operation, request, data):
        ssl_protocols = {'sslv2': QSsl.SslV2,
                         'sslv3': QSsl.SslV3,
                         'tlsv1': QSsl.TlsV1,
                         'tlsv1sslv3': QSsl.TlsV1SslV3,
                         'unknownprotocol': QSsl.UnknownProtocol,
                         'secureprotocols': QSsl.SecureProtocols}

        if self._override_ssl is not None:
            ssl_config = QSslConfiguration.defaultConfiguration()
            ssl_config.setProtocol(ssl_protocols[self._override_ssl])
            request.setSslConfiguration(ssl_config)

        reply = QNetworkAccessManager.createRequest(self.network_manager,
                                                    operation,
                                                    request,
                                                    data)

        return reply

    def override_ssl(self, protocol_id):
        # protocol id is a string like 'sslv3' or 'tlsv1'
        self._override_ssl = protocol_id
```

Ok I typed most of the code from memory, please report if something doesn't work.

Comment: Thanks for your detailed response. I am aware of the 2nd problem associated with some legacy servers only supporting sslv3 protocol. I've talked about that problem in this thread: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13408829/qtnetwork-ssl-handshake-error-on-https-service-oneaccount-com-onlinev2-b-osv2/13785702#13785702 . As for the original problem, I've revised the original post to provide further findings due to further investigation.

Comment: you could try setting the peer certificate verification depth parameter, also globally in the initialization method, so in my load_certs function the third line should be: ssl_config.setPeerVerifyDepth(1) . have a look at: http://srinikom.github.com/pyside-docs/PySide/QtNetwork/QSslConfiguration.html
also if you're accessing a limited set of sites, you could still download all the intermediate certificates from a browser like chrome...

Comment: I've added more findings to the original post at the bottom. It looks I am very close to the root cause of the problem. I am developing a general-purpose web browser which might access any website. So downloading the intermediate certificates manually is the last choice. I did try that. It works well on windows and linux. But no effect on mac somehow.

Comment: Well all browsers ship with a set of root / intermediate certificates, but still, even if you get them all, I doubt it will solve the problem with new/untrusted certs...

Comment: Thanks! Your answer helped me a lot. Here is a nice project with certificates extracted from the Mozilla browser: https://curl.se/docs/caextract.html
There's also a tool you can use to extract it yourself. I just had to use `QSslCertificate.fromDevice` to load all certificates included in the pem file.